# How to assign same value to multiple variables in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two variables and I want to assign the same value to both of them at the same time, something like below:

```
var allGood: Boolean = false
val deviceId: String = "3550200583"
var isValidId: Boolean = false
allGood = isValidId = deviceId.length > 0 && deviceId.length <= 16
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because assignment is not an expression in Kotlin, you can't do multiple assignments that way.  But there are other ways.  The most obvious is simply:

```
isValidId = deviceId.length > 0 && deviceId.length <= 16
allGood = isValidId
```

A more idiomatic (if longer) way is:

```
(deviceId.length > 0 && deviceId.length <= 16).let {
    allGood = it
    isValidId = it
}
```

(By the way, you can simplify the condition to `deviceId.length in 1..16`.)

There are a couple of reasons why Kotlin doesn't allow this.  The main one [is](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignments-as-expressions/1564) that it's incompatible with the syntax for calling a function with named parameters: `fn(paramName = value)`.  But it also avoids any confusion between `=` and `==` (which could otherwise cause hard-to-spot bugs).  See also [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/15).

Comment: This is closer but not actual solution i was looking.  Java has support but seems that Kotlin doesn't.

Comment: I don't think the second way is any more idiomatic than the first one.

Comment: "Java has support but seems that Kotlin doesn't.". Correct. Kotlin has avoided the mistake of supporting this. The answer explains why it's a mistake.

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
var allGood: Boolean = false
val deviceId: String = ...
val isValidId: Boolean = (deviceId.length in 1..16).also { allGood = it }
```

`.also` allows you to perform additional operations with the value that it receives and then returns the original value.

Comment: Best option for this use case in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to do it like this:

```
val deviceId: String = "3550200583";
val condition = deviceId.length > 0 && deviceId.length <= 16
var (allGood, isValidId) = arrayOf(condition, condition);
```

Comment: Aware of this syntax. Not helpful in my case. Thanks.